# Creating path from force edge bundling do not align with node position in D3

Tags: d3.js

I tried to recreate the Mercator projection of nodes in a network and show the bundled edges between those nodes by following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualising-the-mercator-graph-layout-embeddings-using-a-real-world-complex-network-bf065c316b7a)

For some reason the bundled edges are misaligned form the position of the nodes and I can not figure out why.

Here is my code:

```js
var data = {"nodes": {"1": {"k": 0.9992479999999999, "theta": 1.38582, "r": 12.2062}, "2": {"k": 6.84214, "theta": 1.41486, "r": 8.35845}, "3": {"k": 3.87975, "theta": 1.24794, "r": 9.49312}, "4": {"k": 3.87264, "theta": 1.25108, "r": 9.496780000000001}, "5": {"k": 0.980118, "theta": 1.4444700000000001, "r": 12.2448}, "6": {"k": 0.982295, "theta": 1.41229, "r": 12.2404}, "7": {"k": 0.8832969999999999, "theta": 1.3943, "r": 12.4528}, "8": {"k": 1.4808700000000001, "theta": 1.37129, "r": 11.4194}, "9": {"k": 1.30285, "theta": 1.4634200000000002, "r": 11.6755}, "10": {"k": 1.04729, "theta": 1.4543, "r": 12.1122}, "11": {"k": 33.8317, "theta": 0.7633340000000001, "r": 5.16186}, "12": {"k": 0.978433, "theta": 0.887065, "r": 12.2483}, "13": {"k": 3.2869599999999997, "theta": 0.0945006, "r": 9.82473}, "14": {"k": 1.03292, "theta": 0.9003399999999999, "r": 12.1399}, "15": {"k": 0.9252030000000001, "theta": 0.869986, "r": 12.3601}, "16": {"k": 0.876183, "theta": 0.853158, "r": 12.469000000000001}, "17": {"k": 4.81263, "theta": 5.95745, "r": 9.06217}, "18": {"k": 11.4515, "theta": 5.63906, "r": 7.328410000000001}, "19": {"k": 4.68924, "theta": 5.93139, "r": 9.11411}, "20": {"k": 4.77015, "theta": 5.947369999999999, "r": 9.0799}, "21": {"k": 4.83483, "theta": 5.99012, "r": 9.05296}, "22": {"k": 4.826309999999999, "theta": 5.96159, "r": 9.05649}, "23": {"k": 4.85236, "theta": 5.97253, "r": 9.04573}, "24": {"k": 15.539000000000001, "theta": 6.23499, "r": 6.71795}, "25": {"k": 10.7221, "theta": 4.4985, "r": 7.460039999999999}, "26": {"k": 16.4477, "theta": 4.26896, "r": 6.60428}, "27": {"k": 16.3118, "theta": 5.2454, "r": 6.6208800000000005}, "28": {"k": 26.1356, "theta": 0.631512, "r": 5.678059999999999}, "29": {"k": 4.51874, "theta": 1.0991, "r": 9.188189999999999}, "30": {"k": 8.95609, "theta": 1.79397, "r": 7.81999}, "31": {"k": 1.9674, "theta": 6.15614, "r": 10.8512}, "32": {"k": 5.11857, "theta": 6.15794, "r": 8.9389}, "33": {"k": 0.824627, "theta": 0.8390860000000001, "r": 12.5903}, "34": {"k": 1.9683700000000002, "theta": 0.663694, "r": 10.8502}, "35": {"k": 6.30168, "theta": 1.8584, "r": 8.523019999999999}, "36": {"k": 6.2923599999999995, "theta": 1.85647, "r": 8.52598}, "37": {"k": 6.110180000000001, "theta": 1.8197, "r": 8.58474}, "38": {"k": 6.14213, "theta": 1.82575, "r": 8.57431}, "39": {"k": 6.29711, "theta": 1.8577, "r": 8.524469999999999}, "40": {"k": 3.59619, "theta": 4.70288, "r": 9.6449}, "41": {"k": 0.958592, "theta": 4.29816, "r": 12.2892}, "42": {"k": 12.5055, "theta": 4.00964, "r": 7.152310000000001}, "43": {"k": 4.100140000000001, "theta": 4.257619999999999, "r": 9.382610000000001}, "44": {"k": 5.2855099999999995, "theta": 0.45739300000000005, "r": 8.87472}, "45": {"k": 2.4893, "theta": 1.1491799999999999, "r": 10.3807}, "46": {"k": 0.9611850000000001, "theta": 1.10574, "r": 12.2838}, "47": {"k": 2.41014, "theta": 3.09404, "r": 10.4453}, "48": {"k": 0.9815659999999999, "theta": 3.0974, "r": 12.2419}, "49": {"k": 17.3622, "theta": 2.84707, "r": 6.49606}, "50": {"k": 6.08491, "theta": 4.87309, "r": 8.59303}, "51": {"k": 2.20702, "theta": 4.798030000000001, "r": 10.6214}, "52": {"k": 7.13173, "theta": 4.90129, "r": 8.27555}, "53": {"k": 2.90794, "theta": 4.7199, "r": 10.0698}, "54": {"k": 0.729966, "theta": 4.92662, "r": 12.8342}, "55": {"k": 5.18354, "theta": 5.02108, "r": 8.913680000000001}, "56": {"k": 20.5058, "theta": 5.03296, "r": 6.16323}, "57": {"k": 1.72702, "theta": 4.82372, "r": 11.1119}, "58": {"k": 9.27098, "theta": 2.38577, "r": 7.75088}, "59": {"k": 15.0854, "theta": 2.75577, "r": 6.7772}, "60": {"k": 10.812999999999999, "theta": 2.7786, "r": 7.443160000000001}, "61": {"k": 7.61596, "theta": 2.75693, "r": 8.144160000000001}, "62": {"k": 10.84, "theta": 2.77481, "r": 7.4381699999999995}, "63": {"k": 12.6558, "theta": 2.84763, "r": 7.128419999999999}, "64": {"k": 11.4227, "theta": 2.85943, "r": 7.33345}, "65": {"k": 12.9216, "theta": 2.8271900000000003, "r": 7.086860000000001}, "66": {"k": 11.5686, "theta": 2.84925, "r": 7.30807}, "67": {"k": 8.233789999999999, "theta": 3.22245, "r": 7.988160000000001}, "68": {"k": 0.982308, "theta": 2.36692, "r": 12.2404}, "69": {"k": 11.7335, "theta": 3.89405, "r": 7.2797600000000005}, "70": {"k": 11.8279, "theta": 3.90955, "r": 7.263730000000001}, "71": {"k": 11.7601, "theta": 3.8980099999999998, "r": 7.275239999999999}, "72": {"k": 10.5991, "theta": 3.82835, "r": 7.4831199999999995}, "73": {"k": 3.95226, "theta": 0.329843, "r": 9.45608}, "74": {"k": 2.12811, "theta": 3.04788, "r": 10.6942}, "75": {"k": 2.10087, "theta": 3.04493, "r": 10.72}, "76": {"k": 8.81953, "theta": 3.75699, "r": 7.85072}, "77": {"k": 6.95978, "theta": 3.3025300000000004, "r": 8.32436}}, "edges": [{"source": "1", "target": "2"}, {"source": "2", "target": "3"}, {"source": "2", "target": "4"}, {"source": "2", "target": "5"}, {"source": "2", "target": "6"}, {"source": "2", "target": "7"}, {"source": "2", "target": "8"}, {"source": "2", "target": "9"}, {"source": "2", "target": "10"}, {"source": "2", "target": "11"}, {"source": "3", "target": "4"}, {"source": "3", "target": "11"}, {"source": "4", "target": "11"}, {"source": "11", "target": "12"}, {"source": "11", "target": "13"}, {"source": "11", "target": "14"}, {"source": "11", "target": "15"}, {"source": "11", "target": "16"}, {"source": "11", "target": "24"}, {"source": "11", "target": "25"}, {"source": "11", "target": "26"}, {"source": "11", "target": "27"}, {"source": "11", "target": "28"}, {"source": "11", "target": "29"}, {"source": "11", "target": "30"}, {"source": "11", "target": "32"}, {"source": "11", "target": "33"}, {"source": "11", "target": "34"}, {"source": "11", "target": "35"}, {"source": "11", "target": "36"}, {"source": "11", "target": "37"}, {"source": "11", "target": "38"}, {"source": "11", "target": "39"}, {"source": "11", "target": "44"}, {"source": "11", "target": "45"}, {"source": "11", "target": "49"}, {"source": "11", "target": "50"}, {"source": "11", "target": "52"}, {"source": "11", "target": "56"}, {"source": "11", "target": "59"}, {"source": "11", "target": "65"}, {"source": "11", "target": "69"}, {"source": "11", "target": "70"}, {"source": "11", "target": "71"}, {"source": "11", "target": "72"}, {"source": "11", "target": "73"}, {"source": "13", "target": "24"}, {"source": "17", "target": "18"}, {"source": "17", "target": "19"}, {"source": "17", "target": "20"}, {"source": "17", "target": "21"}, {"source": "17", "target": "22"}, {"source": "17", "target": "23"}, {"source": "17", "target": "24"}, {"source": "18", "target": "19"}, {"source": "18", "target": "20"}, {"source": "18", "target": "21"}, {"source": "18", "target": "22"}, {"source": "18", "target": "23"}, {"source": "18", "target": "24"}, {"source": "18", "target": "27"}, {"source": "18", "target": "56"}, {"source": "19", "target": "20"}, {"source": "19", "target": "21"}, {"source": "19", "target": "22"}, {"source": "19", "target": "23"}, {"source": "19", "target": "24"}, {"source": "20", "target": "21"}, {"source": "20", "target": "22"}, {"source": "20", "target": "23"}, {"source": "20", "target": "24"}, {"source": "21", "target": "22"}, {"source": "21", "target": "23"}, {"source": "21", "target": "24"}, {"source": "22", "target": "23"}, {"source": "22", "target": "24"}, {"source": "23", "target": "24"}, {"source": "24", "target": "25"}, {"source": "24", "target": "26"}, {"source": "24", "target": "28"}, {"source": "24", "target": "30"}, {"source": "24", "target": "31"}, {"source": "24", "target": "32"}, {"source": "25", "target": "26"}, {"source": "25", "target": "27"}, {"source": "25", "target": "28"}, {"source": "25", "target": "42"}, {"source": "25", "target": "43"}, {"source": "25", "target": "51"}, {"source": "25", "target": "69"}, {"source": "25", "target": "70"}, {"source": "25", "target": "71"}, {"source": "26", "target": "27"}, {"source": "26", "target": "28"}, {"source": "26", "target": "40"}, {"source": "26", "target": "41"}, {"source": "26", "target": "42"}, {"source": "26", "target": "43"}, {"source": "26", "target": "49"}, {"source": "26", "target": "56"}, {"source": "26", "target": "69"}, {"source": "26", "target": "70"}, {"source": "26", "target": "71"}, {"source": "26", "target": "72"}, {"source": "26", "target": "76"}, {"source": "27", "target": "28"}, {"source": "27", "target": "44"}, {"source": "27", "target": "50"}, {"source": "27", "target": "52"}, {"source": "27", "target": "55"}, {"source": "27", "target": "56"}, {"source": "27", "target": "73"}, {"source": "28", "target": "29"}, {"source": "28", "target": "30"}, {"source": "28", "target": "32"}, {"source": "28", "target": "34"}, {"source": "28", "target": "44"}, {"source": "28", "target": "49"}, {"source": "28", "target": "59"}, {"source": "28", "target": "69"}, {"source": "28", "target": "70"}, {"source": "28", "target": "71"}, {"source": "28", "target": "72"}, {"source": "28", "target": "73"}, {"source": "29", "target": "45"}, {"source": "29", "target": "46"}, {"source": "30", "target": "35"}, {"source": "30", "target": "36"}, {"source": "30", "target": "37"}, {"source": "30", "target": "38"}, {"source": "30", "target": "39"}, {"source": "31", "target": "32"}, {"source": "35", "target": "36"}, {"source": "35", "target": "37"}, {"source": "35", "target": "38"}, {"source": "35", "target": "39"}, {"source": "36", "target": "37"}, {"source": "36", "target": "38"}, {"source": "36", "target": "39"}, {"source": "37", "target": "38"}, {"source": "37", "target": "39"}, {"source": "38", "target": "39"}, {"source": "40", "target": "53"}, {"source": "40", "target": "56"}, {"source": "42", "target": "43"}, {"source": "42", "target": "56"}, {"source": "42", "target": "58"}, {"source": "42", "target": "63"}, {"source": "42", "target": "69"}, {"source": "42", "target": "70"}, {"source": "42", "target": "71"}, {"source": "42", "target": "72"}, {"source": "42", "target": "76"}, {"source": "47", "target": "48"}, {"source": "47", "target": "49"}, {"source": "49", "target": "56"}, {"source": "49", "target": "58"}, {"source": "49", "target": "59"}, {"source": "49", "target": "60"}, {"source": "49", "target": "61"}, {"source": "49", "target": "62"}, {"source": "49", "target": "63"}, {"source": "49", "target": "64"}, {"source": "49", "target": "65"}, {"source": "49", "target": "66"}, {"source": "49", "target": "67"}, {"source": "49", "target": "69"}, {"source": "49", "target": "70"}, {"source": "49", "target": "72"}, {"source": "49", "target": "74"}, {"source": "49", "target": "75"}, {"source": "49", "target": "76"}, {"source": "49", "target": "77"}, {"source": "50", "target": "51"}, {"source": "50", "target": "52"}, {"source": "50", "target": "55"}, {"source": "50", "target": "56"}, {"source": "50", "target": "57"}, {"source": "52", "target": "53"}, {"source": "52", "target": "54"}, {"source": "52", "target": "55"}, {"source": "52", "target": "56"}, {"source": "55", "target": "56"}, {"source": "56", "target": "57"}, {"source": "56", "target": "58"}, {"source": "56", "target": "59"}, {"source": "56", "target": "60"}, {"source": "56", "target": "62"}, {"source": "56", "target": "63"}, {"source": "56", "target": "64"}, {"source": "56", "target": "65"}, {"source": "56", "target": "66"}, {"source": "58", "target": "59"}, {"source": "58", "target": "60"}, {"source": "58", "target": "62"}, {"source": "58", "target": "63"}, {"source": "58", "target": "64"}, {"source": "58", "target": "65"}, {"source": "58", "target": "66"}, {"source": "58", "target": "68"}, {"source": "59", "target": "60"}, {"source": "59", "target": "61"}, {"source": "59", "target": "62"}, {"source": "59", "target": "63"}, {"source": "59", "target": "64"}, {"source": "59", "target": "65"}, {"source": "59", "target": "66"}, {"source": "59", "target": "67"}, {"source": "59", "target": "71"}, {"source": "59", "target": "77"}, {"source": "60", "target": "61"}, {"source": "60", "target": "62"}, {"source": "60", "target": "63"}, {"source": "60", "target": "64"}, {"source": "60", "target": "65"}, {"source": "60", "target": "66"}, {"source": "60", "target": "67"}, {"source": "61", "target": "62"}, {"source": "61", "target": "63"}, {"source": "61", "target": "64"}, {"source": "61", "target": "65"}, {"source": "61", "target": "66"}, {"source": "61", "target": "67"}, {"source": "62", "target": "63"}, {"source": "62", "target": "64"}, {"source": "62", "target": "65"}, {"source": "62", "target": "66"}, {"source": "62", "target": "67"}, {"source": "63", "target": "64"}, {"source": "63", "target": "65"}, {"source": "63", "target": "66"}, {"source": "63", "target": "67"}, {"source": "63", "target": "77"}, {"source": "64", "target": "65"}, {"source": "64", "target": "66"}, {"source": "64", "target": "67"}, {"source": "64", "target": "77"}, {"source": "65", "target": "66"}, {"source": "65", "target": "67"}, {"source": "65", "target": "77"}, {"source": "66", "target": "67"}, {"source": "66", "target": "77"}, {"source": "67", "target": "77"}, {"source": "69", "target": "70"}, {"source": "69", "target": "71"}, {"source": "69", "target": "72"}, {"source": "69", "target": "76"}, {"source": "70", "target": "71"}, {"source": "70", "target": "72"}, {"source": "70", "target": "76"}, {"source": "71", "target": "72"}, {"source": "71", "target": "76"}, {"source": "72", "target": "76"}, {"source": "74", "target": "75"}]}


var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("svg");

size = Math.min(width, height)
var r = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(d3.values(data.nodes).map(d => d.r))).range([0, size / 2]);


node_data = {};
d3.entries(data.nodes).forEach(d => {
    node_data[d.key] = {
        'x': r(d.value.r) * Math.cos(d.value.theta),
        'y': r(d.value.r) * Math.sin(d.value.theta)
    }
});
edge_data = data.edges;

var fbundling = d3
    .ForceEdgeBundling()
    .step_size(.2)
    .compatibility_threshold(.70)
    .nodes(node_data)
    .edges(edge_data);
var results = fbundling();

var d3line = d3
    .line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d['x'];
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d['y'];
    })
    .curve(d3.curveLinear);

results.forEach(function(edge_subpoint_data, i) {
 svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", d3line(edge_subpoint_data, i))
        .style("stroke", "#222")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke-width", 0.45)
        .style("stroke-opacity", .39)
        .attr('transform', `translate(${size/2},${size/2})`)
});

svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(d3.values(node_data))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr('cx', d => d.y)
    .attr('cy', d => d.x)
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .style("opacity", 0.6)
    .attr('transform', `translate(${size/2},${size/2})`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/upphiminn/d3.ForceBundle@master/d3-ForceEdgeBundling.js"></script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle version of the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/syedarehaq/652wuj91/

Comment: You use d.x for x in the line, but d.y for centering on x for the circles: `attr('cx', d => d.y)` , same for y.

Comment: Ahh, such a silly mistake, thanks for pointing out. If you put it as an answer I could accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Andrew Reid's comment, the problem was that for the nodes the x and y coordinates were mistakenly inversed, it should have been:

```
.attr('cx', d => d.x)
.attr('cy', d => d.y)
```

instead of

```
.attr('cx', d => d.y)
.attr('cy', d => d.x)
```